# OutOfMemoryException on start a MVC3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Every time I start the project in debug I get this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Unknown Module.

The application even started running yet, don't know where come from and don't have any stack trace.

Anyone know how can I fix this?

[]'s

Beside the normal stuff of MVC3 and a ModelBinder association, in *Application_Start* I'm loading the log4net configuration.

Comment: And what are you doing in the Application start method? I hope you don't expect us guessing that.

Answer (score 0):

When you comment out the log4net Configuration, does the problem still occur?

(Sorry for posting as an answer)